# Upleveling TargetSDK from 23 to 34

Tags: targetsdkversion

My app is on TargetSDK version 23 right now and have never performed an uplevel for TargetSDKVersion. I'd like to know what I'd need to consider and the issues that I could run into if I want to uplevel to 34 (latest) TargetSDK version.

Appreciate all responses. TIA